# Re-sizing web page causing divs overlap

Tags: css, html, navigationbar

I am having an issue with my webpage.

My div tags on the right side are overlapping onto my center column... I have set a min-width to my parent div tag but it did nothing to help elevate the problem.

Plus my navigation bar is giving me a little issue.. ENGAGEMENT will fall under the ABOUT tab when I re-size my web page. I have `display: block;` and `display: inline;` set in my CSS. It works fine just the re-sizing is hurting my web-page..

My layout is basic..

```
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; margin-top: -18px; clear: both;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;  background-color: white;">
            <p style="padding-top: 3%;font-size:30px; font"><i>Welcome</i></p>
        </div>  

        <div style="width: 100%; display: block; overflow: hidden; ">
            <div><li><a href="http://www.albany.edu/" class="nav">About</a></li></div>
            <div><li><a href="http://albany.bncollege.com/" class="nav">Books</a></li></div> 
            <div><li><a href="#AM" class="nav">Electronics</a></li></div>  
            <div><li><a href="#UA" class="nav">Apparel</a></li></div>
            <div><li><a href="#SP" class="nav">Activities</a></li></div>
            <div><li><a href="#SL" class="nav">Engagement</a></li></div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; background-color:  white; margin-left: 80px;">
        </div>  
        <div id="left-col" style="clear: left;">
        </div>
        <div id="central-col">
        </div>      
        <div id="right-col" style="text-align: center; clear: right; ">
        </div>
        <div id="footer"><p style="text-align: center;">KNOWLEDGE IS POWER</p> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you have given full code (may be on jsfiddle) because it is hard to understand what these divs are doing by looking at your code. (You have made so many of them.)

For your solution, I think you have to remove

```
width: 100%
```

from second and third div.

You have set margin-left to 80px, so whenever you resize the window, it will always have a margin of 80px from left.

Also I want to know the use of

> overflow: hidden;

in your code.

Comment: I added the overflow: hidden property to my navigation bar thinking it would prevent the bar from being affected when the page is re-size. Trying to teach myself the best way I can by testing and trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: but it will omit your contents, wouldn't it?
make it overflow: auto;

Comment: here is a link my web page http://www.albany.edu/~bk838732/SampleWeb_Killebrew.html

Comment: actually you have given total width of 100% to the main page and then you are using width in pixels for various divs, so change all those width and margins in percentage but remember that total width of the page must not extend 100% that is the sum of the width of left_col + central_col + right_col + margins must be 100%.

Comment: Okay, so once I calculate my left col, center col and right col to make sure it stay under the width percentage then everything should run smooth... It should not be too bad. 
Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: Also not forget about the margins (left and right), the total sum must be 100%.